# Cocos2d CCshaky3d in android

Tags: cocos2d-android

I am trying to create a shake effect in my program using cocos2d in android.But when i apply shaky effect that orientation was changed and a black screen will show. What's wrong with this code?

```
    float  width=s.getWidth()/2;
    float height=s.getHeight()/2;
    firstfireImage = CCSprite.node();
    Bitmap bm =   BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),R.drawable.image_01);
    firstfireImage=CCSprite.sprite(bm);
    firstfireImage.setPosition(240,160);


    CCShaky3D shaky=CCShaky3D.action(10,true,ccGridSize.ccg(20,30),1.0f);
    CCRotateTo rotate=CCRotateTo.action(1,190);
    //CCWaves wave=CCWaves.action(1,1.0f,true,true, ccGridSize.ccg(20,30),1);

    runAction(CCRepeatForever.action(CCSequence.actions(shaky)));
    addChild( firstfireImage,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

put your image in asset folder and remove the line bm=... and try this

```
firstfireImage=CCSprite.sprite("image_01.png");
```